# Java - Get all keys of a map recursively

Tags: java, snakeyaml

So currently I'm working on a yml file updater with SnakeYaml, but I have this issue that I don't know how to solve.

This is my class to get all the keys of the yaml file as a Set< String >:

```
public class YamlKeys {

    private static Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>();
    private static String path = "";

    YamlKeys(Map<?, ?> data) {
        getKeysRecursive(data);
    }

    private void getKeysRecursive(final Map<?, ?> data) {
        for(Object key : data.keySet()) {
            final Object value = data.get(key);
            if(key instanceof String) {
                if(path.length() == 0) {
                    path = (String)key;
                } else {
                    path = path+"."+(String)key;
                }
            }
            if(value instanceof Map) {
                getKeysRecursive((Map<?, ?>) value);
            } else {
                keys.add(path);
                if(path.contains(".")) {
                    path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("."));
                }
            }
        }
        path = "";
    }

    Set<String> getKeys() {
        return keys;
    }
}
```

And here is my yml file:

```
FirstKey:
  SecondKey:
    Enabled: true
    ID: "Some text"
    AnotherKey:
      AValue: true
    TestKey:
      TestValue: "More text"
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
new YamlKeys(data).getKeys().stream().forEach(key -> System.out.println(key));
```

And the output is:

```
FirstKey.SecondKey.AnotherKey.AValue
FirstKey.SecondKey.Enabled
FirstKey.SecondKey.ID
TestKey.TestValue
```

The problem is on the last one as it should be "FirstKey.SecondKey.TestKey.TestValue", but the first two keys get removed because of the path reset, this path reset is needed in case more keys are added to "FirstKey", but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Can you provide working example of this data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to pop the last part off the `path` should be applied after you process a map too:

```
if(value instanceof Map) {
    getKeysRecursive((Map<?, ?>) value);
} else {
     keys.add(path);
}
if(path.contains(".")) {
   path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("."));
}
```

Also when you reset the path at the end of `getKeysRecursive` you are discarding the context about how deep in the tree you are. So when your deepest Map is finished processing it clears the `path`, but parent maps haven't finished processing yet.

Trying to manage the state of this single mutable `path` variable from within the recursive calls is tricky. This could be better done by passing the path down like:

`private void getKeysRecursive(final Map<?, ?> data, String parentPath)`

You could also consider using Collections, might clean up a little of the if-else logic around the initial state.

```java
private void getKeysRecursive(final Map<?, ?> data, List<Object> parentPath) {
    for(Object key : data.keySet()) {
        List<Object> path = new ArrayList<>(parentPath);
        path.add(key);
        final Object value = data.get(key);
        if(value instanceof Map) {
            getKeysRecursive((Map<?, ?>) value, path);
        } else {
            keys.add(path.stream().map(Objects::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(".")));
        }
    }
}
```

and start it off with `app.getKeysRecursive(data, Collections.emptyList());`