# Convert map to nested map

Tags: java

I have this map on my YamlFile class, which stores all the keys of the file on this format: String key = "firskey.secondkey.thirdkey", Object value = "Example value"

```
  private static Map<String, Object> deepkeymap;
```

Now, I want to convert my deepkeymap to a nested map that works like this: {firstkey={secondkey={thirdkey="Example value"}}}, my deepkeymap actually stores 4 keys with 4 values (the amount of keys and values will change). I have kind of accomplished this, but not totally as it only converts the last key and value of my deepkeymap, in fact, the example I've put is the output of my nested map, here is the code:

```
public void save() {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> datamap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for(String key : deepkeymap.keySet()) {
            Object value = deepkeymap.get(key);
            int end = key.length();
            for(int start; (start = key.lastIndexOf('.', end - 1)) != -1; end = start) {
                value = new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap(key.substring(start + 1, end), value));
            }
            datamap.putAll(new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap(key.substring(0, end), value)));
        }
        System.out.println("Datamap: "+datamap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, output is:

```
Datamap: {firstkey={secondkey={thirdkey="Example value"}}}
```

But it should have another 3 keys as deepkeymap contains 4 keys with their respective 4 values, I have already checked they are stored on it and no one has a null value, doing a debug on the keySet loop printing keys and values.

Comment: This is fraught with problems.  The values and keys may be strings or maps.   And it sounds like you could have variable levels of keys.  Imo, this would be cumbersome to use (it would probably require `instanceof` checks and `casting`).  I would recommend  you discuss your overall task that warrants this.  Someone may be able to assist you to come  up with a more appropriate solution.  Or just leave it alone and use as is.

Comment: @WJS actually every key of my deepkeymap is a String with an Object value, I'm sure of it because I'm using a class that converts every key of a yml file stored on the resources folder to this map on a dot separated string form, checks are done there so my deepkeymap is 100% a <String, Object> map and the conversion is working as showed on the output, but, it only outputs the last key stored on the deepkeymap.

Comment: There exist YAML parsers which return data structures like what you're talking about. You might consider using one of those instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm using SnakeYAML for this, but the point here is that I have this method set(String path, Object value), where path is a "dot.separated.string" that represents a nested map, same happens with get(String path), so the solution I have here is to create a Map<String, Object> with the dot separated strings and their values, then, when I want to save the file, convert the dot separated strings into nested maps and dump them into the file, here is another post about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938579/java-get-all-keys-of-a-map-recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the code below. Factory method fails for incorrect input, also, there is only toString for the DeepKeyMap. Below is a JUnit test, that just runs the code and tests nothing. You can extract the DeepKeyMap into a seperate class if you will use it in the future.

```
public class MapTest
{
    static class DeepKeyMap
    {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        public void put(
                String path,
                Object value
        )
        {
            String[] split = path.split("\\.");

            this.put(split, value);
        }

        public void put(
                String[] path,
                Object value
        )
        {
            Map<String, Object> deepestMap = createMapsToTheDeepestKey(path);
            String deepestKey = path[path.length - 1];

            deepestMap.put(deepestKey, value);
        }

        private Map<String, Object> createMapsToTheDeepestKey(String[] path)
        {
            Map<String, Object> deepestMap = map;

            for (int i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++)
            {
                String key = path[i];
                deepestMap = getDeeperMap(deepestMap, key);
            }

            return deepestMap;
        }

        private Map<String, Object> getDeeperMap(
                Map<String, Object> deepestMap,
                String key
        )
        {
            if (!deepestMap.containsKey(key))
            {
                deepestMap.put(key, new HashMap<>());
            }

            return (Map<String, Object>) deepestMap.get(key);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return map.toString();
        }

        public static DeepKeyMap from(Map<String, Object> original)
        {
            DeepKeyMap result = new DeepKeyMap();

            // the for loop can be minimized to
            // original.forEach(result::put);
            for (var entry : original.entrySet())
            {
                result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test()
    {
        Map<String, Object> original = Map.of("flat", "First Level",
                "nested.value.one", "Second Level",
                "nested.value.two", "Third Level",
                "nested.different.value.one", "Fourth Level"
        );

        DeepKeyMap deepMap = DeepKeyMap.from(original);

        System.out.println(deepMap);
    }
}
```

Edit: I refactored the code above a bit. Hopefully it is a bit more clear what it does.

Answer (score -2):

I would not use it like that, you can have there identical keys on different levels, which is not the intention of a Map.

Also, you may produce a construct that has as type of key either a map or a string. This brings various uncertainties.

You should consider using other data structures or a database.

What is your intention, maybe we can assist you.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment and basically repeats what I already said.  You will be able to comment when you get 50+ rep.